# Does any actor model in java allow grouping of tasks to be done?

Tags: java, actor, actor-model

I have 1000 rows of data in mysql that i need to update based on some logic which for some reason cannot be done in mysql using batch update and must be done in java.I need to split the jobs into 20 manageable units of 50 tasks each,so for each group i shall have 50 actors doing the jobs.

I have made this diagram to show what i mean

[image]

What actor model in java can allow me group actors this way?.

Comment: Well, Akka (http://akka.io/) can certainly do it.

Comment: There seem not to be a section on he docs on the subject of grouping actors.

Comment: Well, you would have an actor that spawns the 50 sub-actors that do the work. When they have all terminated, the actor would fire up another 50. Or did you mean something more automatic?

Comment: That's what i meant. Sub-actors is a new concept to me.Can sub actor pass message between each other?.Anyway,i thought that akka would have a section of dealing with actors as thread groups would.

Comment: By "sub actor", I meant a subordinate to the supervisor actor. Certainly, you can have the actors talk to each other. Akka has a hierarchical naming system to allow actors to find each other; "../*" would be the name of all the sibling actors.

Comment: The [`Spring Batch`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/reference/html/spring-batch-intro.html) best suits for batch processing along with *Concurrent batch / on-line processing* and *Parallel Processing*

Comment: Thanks @user3218114 ,i will have a look at it.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out by @Bob, you can easily do this with [Akka](http://akka.io). Your actor supervision hierarchy would be like this: 1 `SuperMaster` Actor, starts 20 `Master` Actors, which each will be responsible for one chunk of work. They ask `SM` for the work, and create 50 `Slave` actors, delegating the work to them. You can setup a [Supervision Strategy](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/general/supervision.html) that will determine if a Slave dies, you need to restart that one piece of work, or if you should drop the entire "group" and tell the SuperMaster that this group of work failed etc. If all a `Slave` finishes his work, it tells so to the `Master`. If all work is done (the `M` got 50 "work done" messages), it can tell it's `SuperMaster` that all the work has been completed, and we're done processing the job.

You can model failure and recovery (as in – "keep trying until it succeeds" or "abort all execution if a group fails" etc) very nicely using Akka's supervision hierarchies. As for spreading the work – yes that is also easy and partially already described in how I laid out the supervision interactions.

Hope this helps, happy hakking!